# How do Web Applications communicate with a server?

Tags: ajax, web-services, rest, soap, interface

Let's say I wanted to create a collaborative web application where users can simultaneously work on e.g. a diagram. I have my interactive web site (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) on the client side, and let's say a Java application synchronizing a centralized model on the server side. **How would client and server exchange messages?** To get a better idea of how the system is supposed to work like, here are some details and a small illustration:

[image]

#### Requirements

- The underlaying technology should support authorized communication to show/hide sensitive information.
- The model of the diagram should only exist on the server (centralized model, no copies), whereby changes should be broadcasted to other users (other browsers who are currently editing the same document).
- After receiving changes to the model, the server shall perform computationally higher demanding tasks such as consistency checks and inform the user if e.g. an action is invalid.

#### Constraints

- The system must not poll or set flags (it should be a direct communication).
- The website must not be reloaded during use.
- Software running on the client must be restricted to JavaScript.

### Technology I've found

Here are some of the solutions I've looked at, ranked from (imho) most suitable to least, whereby I'm not sure if the list is even complete and all my assumptions are correct.

- Java Web Service using `javax.jws` - The service would offer an API described by WSDL and be capable of responding  with SOAP messages using the HTTP protocol, but can JavaScript process these messages?
- Servlets & Java Server Pages (JSPs) - Would, as far as I know, require a page reload to fetch new content (isn't this pretty much the same as PHP? Both are executed on the server to generate HTML pages..)

I've already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390944/how-a-website-and-a-web-application-communicate) which, however, does not provide concrete technologies in the answer. Thank you for any hints and clarification, I dearly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you try websockets since connections will be persistent between clients and server and any of them can send a message at any time.

You could implement a websocket server in Java on the server and use Javascript's built in websockets functionallity on the clients.

Take a look at https://www.websocket.org/ to learn more about websockets.

Comment: Sidenote: not supported in MSIE 8, Opera mini and older Android Browsers.

Comment: It's like all of my dreams became true! WebSockets sound awesome, and I didn't even know them before, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already found out, there are many approaches to this common problem.

SOAP (sometimes called "Web Services" or "WS*") is a standard that was developed for application to application communication. It's strengths are precise specifications (and therefore many good libraries), interface sharing for client and server (through WSDL), and discoverability.

However, SOAP has very limited -if any- support in Browsers.

The most common modern approach is probably RESTful web services based on XML or JSON. When used in a browser as client, JSON is preferred, as the unmarshalling is trivial in JavaScript. Many frameworks and libraries like Angular and jQuery take on the tedious cross-browser AJAX request crafting. Some boilerplate is required to wrap the data in HTML, however. This downside can also be an upside if you consider the cleaner architecture and maintainability.

Since you're using Java on your server, you might also want to look into JSFs AJAX capabilities. It doesn't really use REST (no well-defined resources), but loads server-side rendered chunks of your HTML page asynchronously (read: AJAX) and re-renders them in the DOM. This can be seen as a compromise between real REST and full page reloading. The good side of it is you don't have to define any resources but your backing beans. The downsides are: possible overhead, since you're downloading HTML instead of pure data; and bad testability since you cannot access the rendered chunks outside the JSF context.

---

Wholly different issues are 1. the synchronization of concurrent requests and 2. communication with clients from server. For the latter you can either look into Web Sockets (the next big thing) or the good-old polling.

If concurrent edits of the same data are a concern to you, you'll have to implement a sort of strategy to tell whether edits can be merged or whether one has to be declined. The client will need to handle such situations and offer the user reviewing, overriding or reverting etc.

---

**EDIT:** more on Java servlets and JSP

Servlets are nothing but Java classes that handle specific HTTP requests, usually bound to certain URL paths. They're comparable to PHP pages: In PHP the web server gets a request and searches for a corresponding PHP file. Then it parses the PHP script and returns the response. Servlets do the same, only the syntax is very different. JSP is mostly a try at bringing more PHP-ish syntax to Java. Behind the curtains, they're rendered to pure Java servlets.

Java servlets have a long history which is older than AJAX, but many frameworks have taken on the challenge of implementing flexible resource handling on the server. Most notably Jersey and RESTEasy, which are implementations of the Java EE standard JAX-RS; and Spring, which is a request-based framework that competes well against Java EE standards. Then there is also JSF, which is sometimes called a successor of JSP. To the user it's little different than JSP, but the syntax is nicer and IMHO it is more feature-rich than JSP. Especially considering extensions like [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/). In contrast to JSP, JSF embraces AJAX and many built-in components are capable of communicating with the server using AJAX, including calling Java functions and re-rendering parts of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for the superb breakdown! I wish I could award both of you the "correct answer", but WebSockets just nailed it. Could you briefly tell me where Servlets & JSPs would fall into place? I guess they are completely unsuitable. I am aware that I need to deal with concurrency issues on the server, but I got that covered, thanks :)